# SQL Server FILESTREAM access denied

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I have my machine and a database server on the same Windows domain. I also have a staging machine that is not on the domain.

From my machine, I am able to perform any and all operations using FILESTREAM without trouble. From the staging machine, my application is able to use TSQL as it pleases, but the moment it tries to open a `SqlFileStream`, I receive 'access is denied.`

The staging machine, the database server, and my machine all have a local user set up with an identical name and password so that the application can use integrated security to connect to SQL Server. Since FILESTREAM is the only thing not working for the non-domain machine, I am wondering if I am missing something in the FILESTREAM documentation or if the documentation fails to specify that only Active Directory will suffice for integrated security, or of course if there is something I can do to make my situation work.

Comment: What access has been granted specifically to the SQL Server service account? I don't think it's the connecting user you need to worry about in that case.

Comment: I'm unsure; is there something in particular for me to check? Both application machines (my own and the staging machine) are accessing the same SQL Server instance and database on the same host.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be a firewall-related problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the user account, as queries are able to run without issue. The problem is firewall-related. Make sure that ports 139 and 445 are open between the application server and the database server, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283098.aspx:

> To use FILESTREAM in a firewall-protected environment, both the client
>   and server must be able to resolve DNS names to the server that
>   contains the FILESTREAM files. FILESTREAM requires the Windows
>   file-sharing ports 139 and 445 to be open.

Comment: I'm glad this resolved the issue, but just to be clear: queries and filestream/filetable/file system access are two different things, and just because one is working fine doesn't mean it's not the issue for the other.